# O comando prompt muda o valor?

Tags: javascript, prompt

Fazendo um código simples de calcular quanto eu preciso para alcança a média da minha faculdade.

O problema que não consigo receber os valores pelo teclado, uso o comando *prompt* mas o resultado não fica o mesmo.

Eu coloco esse código e calcula normalmente.

```
<script>
    var ap1 = 4.2;
    var ap2 = 9.4;
    var ap3nota = 5 - ((ap1 + ap2) * 0.3);
    var ap3questoes = (ap3nota / 0.16);
    var nota = ap3questoes * 0.4;

    document.write(nota);
    document.write(Math.round(ap3questoes));
</script>
```

Mas com o *prompt* o resultado fica errado.

```
<script>
    var ap1 = prompt("Nota da ap1");
    var ap2 = prompt("Nota da ap2");
    var ap3nota = 5 - ((ap1 + ap2) * 0.3);
    var ap3questoes = (ap3nota / 0.16);
    var nota = ap3questoes * 0.4;

    document.write(nota);
    document.write(Math.round(ap3questoes));
</script>
```

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo (quando tiver pontuação suficiente).

Answer (score 2):

Não, ele não muda, não tem como ele mudar. Na verdade a pergunta prate de uma premissa errada.

Em tudo o que você for fazer em um código precisa entender tudo o que está acontecendo. Em especial em uso de funções precisa ler a documentação por completo antes de usá-la. No caso da função [`prompt()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt) )não é um comando) a documentação diz que o retorno dela é um dado do tipo `string`. Isso faz toda diferença. Se o retorno é um texto e você tentar fazer uma conta aritmética com ela não acontecerá o que espera. Então seu primeiro código é completamente diferente do segundo, um calcula números e o outro calcula textos.

Como você ainda quer operar em números precisa converter o resultado de `prompt()` em números. Partindo do princípio que usa valores com ponto decimal e que não é necessário exatidão no cálculo, pode usar a função [`parseFloat()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat). O que fará antes de usá-la?

O código poderia ficar assim:

```js
var ap3questoes = (5 - (parseFloat(prompt("Nota da ap1")) + parseFloat(prompt("Nota da ap2"))) * 0.3) / 0.16;
document.write(ap3questoes * 0.4);
document.write(Math.round(ap3questoes));
```

Então está resolvido? Não, ainda há problemas. Como eu disse só funciona se você não quer exatidão, teste números diferentes e verá que há casos que não dá o número que deseja. E nada tem a ver com o `prompt()`, e sim com [o tipo `float` que não é adequado para exatidão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/219211/101), então dá erro até com o número direto. A maioria dos programadores ignoram isto e tem seus códigos errados sem perceber por anos.

Existe um erro de encavalamento da informação apresentada em tela nos dois códigos, é secundário, mas é bom deixar claro que há.

Por fim, e se a pessoa digitar um formato inválido? Um código correto não pode exigir que a pessoa digite certo para funcionar, a não ser que ele informe isso depois de validar. Claro, ele não faz milagre, não vai arrumar o problema, mas seu código precisa identificar que houve um erro de digitação, como por exemplo uma letra ter sido digitada, ou um ponto equivocado. Seria algo assim:

```js
function teste() {
    var t1 = prompt("Nota da ap1");
    if (isNaN(t1)) return;
    var t2 = prompt("Nota da ap2");
    if (isNaN(t2)) return;
    var ap3questoes = (5 - (parseFloat(t1) + parseFloat(t2)) * 0.3) / 0.16;
    document.write(ap3questoes * 0.4);
    document.write(" - ");
    document.write(Math.round(ap3questoes));
}
teste();
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/JavaScript/Algorithm/Grade.js).

Answer (score 0):

Deve converter os valores passados via `prompt` para *float*:

```js
    var ap1 = parseFloat(prompt("Nota da ap1"));
    var ap2 = parseFloat(prompt("Nota da ap2"));
    var ap3nota = 5 - ((ap1 + ap2) * 0.3);
    var ap3questoes = (ap3nota / 0.16);
    var nota = ap3questoes * 0.4;

    document.write(nota);
    document.write(Math.round(ap3questoes));
```

**PS:** Você deve digitar os valores com `.` (ponto) como separador decimal. Ex.: `1.2` ao invés de `1,2`.